# Cannot display new icon for the application

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to change the icon of the application, and I have changed it and the project builds completely fine.

But when the application starts, I still see the default icon on the taskbar. On the otherhand, when I click on About, I can see the new Icon.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you read a tutorial about that?

Comment: No, I did not. I thought, if I change the image, it should work. It will be great if you could give some link for the tutorial. Thanks.

Comment: I believe you have to provide an image for each possible size (e.g., 16x16, 32x32, etc.). Look at the icon editor to see where you select the size.

Comment: add an image for all icon sizes.

Comment: you dont need image for every possible size. i have used this code for long time: `WNDCLASS wc; wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));` works fine even if i only allow 16x16 images...

Comment: @Rookie: Thanks. I have a 32x32, 24 bit image. Where do I use the above code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the resource ID of your icon is the lowest of all the icons in your resources. Windows will display the icon with the *lowest* ID.